# How can I achieve Auto refresh contacts list like whatsapp in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I’m creating messaging app like whatsapp. In my message app, my contacts list doesn’t refresh anymore. I have added some new contacts on my iOS and i don’t see them on my contact list, But i receive messages from them and only the number shows.

I can achieve by manually clicking  a menu “Refresh contacts”. It works. But how can i achieve AutoRefresh contacts list? How can i detect ios addressbook changes?

Comment: What's in 'app server'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register for the [`CNContactsStoreDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1403253-cncontactstoredidchange) notification so you know when it's time to refresh your list.